# Printing stdout with pythontex and line referencing

Tags: beamer, python

I have a problem with PythonTeX and Beamer : I don't understand why the code below doesn't work: `\stdoutpythontex` is supposed to print the last output of the last block of python instructions, but it doesn't here.

Moreover, when you call  `\stderrpythontex`, the line number is false, even with the option `fragile=singleslide`.

Could you please help me with this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage[makestderr]{pythontex}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Affichage à l'écran: Commande \pyv{print()} }  
\begin{itemize}
\item En mode console:   résultats automatiquement affichés.
\item Dans l'éditeur: utiliser \pyv{print()}
\end{itemize}
%

\begin{pyblock}[][numbers=left]
a, b =  2, 3
print(a, 'hello', a+b)
\end{pyblock}
%
a pour résultat
\stdoutpythontex

De plus, 
\begin{pyblock}[][numbers=left]
a = 5
print('a vaut ' a)
\end{pyblock}
donne
\stderrpythontex
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: ok, sorry I'll do it from now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your current configuration, everything is executed in a *single* Python session.  The second chunk of code triggers a syntax error, which is caught *before* any code is executed.  The syntax error prevents any code from running, so the first chunk never gets to print.

The line numbering shown in the error (`4`) is correct, because the syntax error was in the 4th line of your code (again, everything is in a single session).  This didn't line up with the line numbering shown in the slide, though, because you weren't using `firstnumber=last`.

If you want both examples to work, independently, then you should put them in separate sessions.  Maybe use `\begin{pyblock}[stdout][numbers=left]` for the first one, and `\begin{pyblock}[stderr][numbers=left]` for the second one.

Comment: OK, thanks for these explanations (though I spent many hours on your exhaustive documentation, I realize I didn't understand the idea of many sessions, which is actually great!) By the way, thanks again for you PythonTex package!

Comment: @guillaume [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.